# Is it possible to change position of two groups in regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse complex number, it consists of two floats, one of them ends with i or j ignore case. And there are also many spaces and different delimiters. I have now two groups

```
/^\s*[0]*((?:\d+)?(?:[.\,]\d+)?)?(?:\s*\s*[0]?)?([+-]\s*(?:\d+)?(?:[.\,]\d+)?[i,j])?\s*/im
```

but, `7j + 8,65` is also complex number. Well, I can make super long regexp with re im and im re subgroups, but it is absolutely unreadable.

Question: can I group long part of regex in javascript and give it a name? (I can store part of regex in string and concatenate strings, of course, but it is not what I am looking for). Is it possible to make unordered match and capture groups despite their positions?

P.S. This is hobby project, so I can use modern browsers with js 1.7.

UPD

`^\s*[0]*` - starts with spaces and leading zeros
`((?:\d+)?(?:[.\,]\d+)?)` - decimal, then maybe delimiter and decimal after it
`(?:\s*\s*[0]?)` - unused spaces and leading zeros before second part
`([+-]\s*(?:\d+)?(?:[.\,]\d+)?[i,j])?` - second decimal part ends with i, j , and yes, i and j are included into second capturing group
`?\s*/im` - trailing spaces. Then ignore case and multiline

UPD

I made solution, but now it looks like calculator

```
var parseComplex = function (str) {
    'use strict';
    var groups = str
            .replace(/\s/g, '')
            .match(/[+-]?(?:\d*)?(?:[.,]\d*)?(:?[i,j])?/gim),
        im = 0.0,
        re = 0.0,
        i,
        len = groups.length,
        grLen;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
        grLen = groups[i].length;
        if (groups[i] !== '') {
            if (groups[i].substr(grLen - 1).match(/[i,j]/i)) {
                im += parseFloat(groups[i].substr(0, grLen - 1));
            } else {
                re += parseFloat(groups[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        re: re,
        im: im
    };
}
console.log(parseComplex("1.23 + 0.9j - 7i"));
console.log(parseComplex("0.3i - 133"));
console.log(parseComplex("8 + 9.09J"));
console.log(parseComplex("3i + 8j"));
```

Comment: do you need explanation?

Comment: Not really. I was just making an observation. :-)

Comment: I think I'd code it manually: trimming the string, splitting by operand (+ or -), check which group has an i or j... and it wouldn't be much longer than that regexp

Comment: In JS I don't think you can have named capture groups.

Comment: And in what language I can have named groups? I haven't touched Perl for years and don't know python good, maybe there are some languages with such possibilities?

Comment: If you need to reorder groups use this logic `console.log('abc'.replace(/(a)(b)(c)/, '$3$2$1'));`

Comment: it sounds to me like you need a tokenizer and parser, not a regexp...

Comment: @NPE [Here is the regex as a diagram](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Cs*%5B0%5D*\(\(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B\)%3F\(%3F%3A%5B.%5C%2C%5D%5Cd%2B\)%3F\)%3F\(%3F%3A%5Cs*%5Cs*%5B0%5D%3F\)%3F\(%5B%2B-%5D%5Cs*\(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B\)%3F\(%3F%3A%5B.%5C%2C%5D%5Cd%2B\)%3F%5Bi%2Cj%5D\)%3F%5Cs*%2Fim)

Comment: @IvanIvanov are you writing a general expression parser for which this is just one particular case?

Comment: no, I write Indra's Pearls comprehensions using canvas

Comment: @IvanIvanov about any decent language with regex support has named capture groups... Unfortunately JS does not. Heck, it doesn't even support lookbehind. `</rant>`